# Problems with a sql statement

Tags: mysql

I have a mistake in this sql statement and I don't know why:

```
SELECT t1.id_servidor_virtual as id_servidor_virtual,
    t1.nombre_servidor as nombre_servidor, 
    t1.plantilla as plantilla, 
    (SELECT tt1.descripcion
        FROM sku_precios tt1
        WHERE tt1.id_sku_precio = 'VM --') as c_sv,
    t1.sv_pvp as c_sv_pvp,
    t1.sv_pvp_dist as c_sv_pvp_dist,
    (SELECT tt1.descripcion
        FROM sku_precios tt1
        WHERE tt1.id_sku_precio = 'VCPU --') as c_cpu,
    t1.cpu_cant as c_cpu_cant,
    t1.cpu_pvp as c_cpu_pvp,
    t1.cpu_pvp_dist as c_cpu_pvp_dist,
    (SELECT tt1.descripcion
        FROM sku_precios tt1
        WHERE tt1.id_sku_precio = 'RAM --') as c_ram,
    t1.ram_cant as c_ram_cant,
    t1.ram_pvp as c_ram_pvp,
    t1.ram_pvp_dist as c_ram_pvp_dist,
    aletras(t1.ram_cant) as c_ram_unidad,
    (SELECT tt1.descripcion
        FROM sku_precios tt1 
        WHERE tt1.id_sku_precio = 'HDSTD --') as c_hdd,
    t1.hdd_cant as c_hdd_cant,
    t1.hdd_pvp as c_hdd_pvp,
    t1.hdd_pvp_dist as c_hdd_pvp_dist,
    aletras(t1.hdd_cant) as c_hdd_unidad,
    (SELECT tt1.descripcion
        FROM sku_precios tt1
        WHERE tt1.id_sku_precio = 'IPP --') as c_ip,
==> (t1.ip_pvpt1.ip_polled_pvpt1.ip_custom_pvp) as c_ip_pvp, 
    (t1.ip_pvp_distt1.ip_polled_pvp_distt1.ip_custom_pvp_dist) as c_ip_pvp_dist, 
    t1.id_servidor_virtual as parent_id, 
    (SELECT COUNT(t2.id_servicio_adicional) 
        FROM servicios_adicionales t2 
        WHERE t2.id_servidor_virtual = t1.id_servidor_virtual) as cant_sa,
    DATE_FORMAT(t2.f_inicio_contrato, '%d-%m-%Y') as f_inicio_contrato, 
    DATE_FORMAT(t2.f_fin_contrato, '%d-%m-%Y') as f_fin_contrato, 
    (SELECT tt2.n_pedido 
        FROM servidores_virtuales tt1 
        INNER JOIN pedidos tt2 ON tt2.id_pedido = tt1.id_pedido 
        WHERE tt1.id_servidor_virtual = t2.id_pedido_actualizado) as n_pedido_actualizado, 
    (SELECT t3.descuento 
        FROM albaranes t3 
        WHERE t3.id_pedido = t1.id_pedido 
        AND t3.id_cuenta_emisora = 2) as descuento 
FROM servidores_virtuales t1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN pedidos t2 ON t2.id_pedido = t1.id_pedido 
WHERE t1.id_pedido = 230;
```

The mistake is:

> Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.ip_custom_pvp)                as c_ip_pvp, ' at line 32

Line 32 is marked with `==>`.

Could you help me?. Thanks so much

Comment: This looks fishy `t1.ip_pvpt1.ip_polled_pvpt1.ip_custom_pvp` as well as `t1.ip_pvp_distt1.ip_polled_pvp_distt1.ip_custom_pvp_dist` in the very next line.

Comment: You could tell us which one is line 32 but that would spoil the joy of counting ourselves.

Comment: @Álvaro, such a "Australian" sense of humour (that's a compliment by the way). I've clearly indicated line 32 now :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
t1.ip_pvpt1.ip_polled_pvpt1.ip_custom_pvp
```

Are you sure you shouldn't have some other characters in there, like a `+` or `-` sign for example?

It seems to me that that's three *separate* columns:

```
t1.ip_pvp   t1.ip_polled_pvp   t1.ip_custom_pvp
```

which should be joined in some other manner than just removing the white space between them :-)

That's not the only occurrence by the way, just the first one I picked up on. There's one on the following line as well.

The reason MySQL is complaining is that you're apparently breaking the `schema.object` naming standard by having *two* `.` characters in the fill object name (hence three rather than two levels).